# To find out $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{2^{{2}^n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do i find $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{2^{{2}^n}}$$. I tried using L'Hop rule but coudnot get much far.

Thanks for help

Comment: You should stop thinking L'Hospital's rule can do anything! It is equivalent to Taylor's formula at order 1, and it has some conditions to check to be valid, which no one ever checks.

Comment: It's like a hospital for those who are getting sick trying to solve mathematic puzzles...Normally it apply for limite 0/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{n^n}{2^{{2}^n}}=\exp(n\ln(n)-2^n\ln(2))$.

Standard asymptotics tell you $n\ln(n)-2^n\ln(2) \to -\infty$, hence the answer is $0$.

Comment: Can you explain first step

Comment: @SophieClad Take logarithms.

Comment: Please elaborate second step

Comment: @SophieClad: you can use $2^{n}/n^{2}\to\infty$. Just write the expression as $n^{2}((\log n) /n-(2^{n}/n^{2})\log 2)$ and then use $(\log n) /n\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $a_n=\frac{n^n}{2^{2^n}}$. Note that 
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{2^{2^{n+1}}}}{\frac{n^n}{2^{2^n}}}
=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\frac{n+1}{2^{2^n}}\to e\cdot 0=0
$$
since the quotient in $<1$, it follows that $a_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Noting $2^n>n^2, n>4$, use the root test:
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^n}{2^{2^n}}}=\frac{n}{2^{\frac{2^n}{n}}}<\frac{n}{2^{\frac{n^2}{n}}}=\frac{n}{2^n}\to0, \ n\to\infty$$
So the series converges by root and comparison tests.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$n^n = 2^{\log_2(n^n)} = 2^{n\log_2(n)},$$
and for large $n$:
$$n\log_2(n)\ll n^2\ll 2^n.$$

Comment: How did you get these inequalities?

Comment: @SophieClad, can be checked using L'H^opital.